# Select atribute with max value

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, sql-order-by, sql-limit

How can i select Company name with max count of Employers between 2 dates with using subquery, main problem is that i have 2 same dates with 2 max values, and i need to take only first of it in subquery

```
select Company.CompanyName from Company 
where FoundingDate between (select top (1) with ties FoundingDate
from Company order by FoundingDate desc) and '2020-11-30' 
group by Company.CompanyName
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you have just one row per founding date, then just `order by` and `top`:

```
select top (1) with ties FoundingDate, EmplCount
from Company 
order by EmplCount desc
```

*If* you have more thane one row per date, and you want to sum the corresponding counts, then you need aggregation as well:

```
select top (1) with ties FoundingDate, sum(EmplCount) as sumEmplCount
from Company 
group by FoundingDate
order by sumEmplCount desc
```

Comment: I apologize for the incomplete question, I wanted to do it through a subquery 
`select Company.CompanyName from Company 
where FoundingDate between (select top (1) with ties FoundingDate
from Company order by FoundingDate desc) and '2020-11-30' 
group by Company.CompanyName`

Comment: @SashaDrozdiuk: I have no idea what you mean. If the above queries do not do what you want, then you might want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65369742/10676716) to provide proper sample data and desired results, in order to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Company 
where FoundingDate between (select top (1) with ties FoundingDate
from Company order by FoundingDate desc) and '2020-11-30' 
group by Company.Id, Company.CompanyName, Company.DirectorName, Company.EmplCount,    Company.FoundingDate

select * from Company
where FoundingDate between (select max(FoundingDate) from Company where EmplCount = (select max(EmplCount) from Company)) and '2020-11-30'
```

2 Kind of answer